# jQuery AJAX CORS with ASP.NET WCF service not working despite web.config entries

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, cors

I'm trying to figure out what it is I'm missing in my approach that's preventing my WCF service from being accessed. If I try to access the service via an AJAX request from the same domain, there's no issue.

I've taken the advice I've seen elsewhere on the site to add to the `<httpProtocol>` tag in the web.config in order to enable CORS, but it doesn't seem to be working (note the first few elements in customHeaders are there for different security reasons):

```
<location path="FooBar.svc">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Request-Method" value="POST"/>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-Custom-Header" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Despite this being in place, I still get an error (using IE Developer Tools) when trying to call the service from a separate page: "XMLHttpRequest for ... required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)"

My jQuery ajax call (Post) has values set for use with CORS, as well:

```
 crossDomain: true,
 xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
```

I've even tried adding a fix for potential IE XDR issues, from https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js, with no effect (I'm using IE11, so I wouldn't expect it)

Anyone have any ideas as to what might be going wrong here?

(EDIT: the service itself is set up with these Attributes, if it makes a difference:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

)

(EDIT 2: In case it's meaningful, the service has to be part of an all-HTTPS site which uses Forms Authentication - and the service needs to use the same login credentials as the site.
)

Comment: Have you tried calling the service using something like postman? Can you see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the http response headers?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't install anything on my work machine, so I've got to wait for the byzantine process of requesting it to go through before I can get any helpful tools in place (and the service isn't available on the outside yet). I was hoping to get a jump start on this.

Comment: You mention you are using forms auth. Do you perform an initial call to the service for this authentication?

Comment: I'm not doing an initial authentication call. Do you have a good link for doing that? Wouldn't I be getting a different error based on the authentication if that was the issue?

Comment: Or no, apparently it's a known issue that ASP.NET FormsAuthentication returns a 302 rather than a 401 in this situation... that's really irritating

Comment: Have you tried enabling CORS...refer http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 7):

Enabling CORS to true in backend server where service is hosted should ideally solve the problem. However there is one more way... You can have a wrapper in between jQuery code and WCF service ( **Note:** It's one of the approach you have to suggest in the team when you do not have the access to modify for example htaccess file in apache where we set the CORS to have access to other domain accessing our service). So the approach goes like this....

> `jQuery Code ->   Wrapper (Webmethod in .NET)  ->  WCF service`

jQuery code and Wrapper resides in the same domain. jQuery calls webmethod which in turn fire a call to respective WCF service method to get the data. The downfall of this approach is that the request traverse through one more layer, the reason why I have mentioned Note in the beginning.

Comment: Would there be something other than the entries in the web.config to enable CORS? Do I have to change something within IIS itself?

Comment: check out the SSL as said by ViajyP. Just nitpicking I have encountered similar type for different issue for woff files, I would suggest post ssl changes reboot the whole IIS.

Answer (score 6):

Your `<customHeaders>` web.config section is set up for CORS requests without credentials. You need a different configuration to allow CORS requests with credentials:

1. Set an additional `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header to `true`.
2. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header cannot be set to `*`. You have to return a case-sensitive match for the CORS request origin/host.

*Source*: [7.2 Resource Sharing Check (W3C Recommendation for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-sharing-check-0)

Comment: Still no change in behavior

Answer (score 5):

If your service is on HTTPS and if you are using self signed SSL Certificate then Cross Domain calls will **Fail** despite `web.config` setting done for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. You should try importing **Valid SSL Certificate** into your IIS and see what you get.

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: this is how the browser behaves. This is to avoid cross site scripting (XXS) vulnerability. To overcome this for testing purpose; you can try following steps: 1) Open your cross domain page having Ajax request in first tab of your browser. 2) Open any HTTPS page of your website containing WCF server in tab 2. 3) As you have self signed SSL; you should get Certificate warning and "I understand risk...continue" message with link. 4) click that continue link 5) now again come to tab 1 which have other domain page 6) refresh it and your Ajax to WCF should work. On Prod, you will have valid SSL.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried with $.support.cors = true in jquery.

Comment: Sorry, that's not changing anything, at least on its own.

Answer (score 4):

With WCF, you need to do more than just adding the custom headers in `web.config`. Just editing `web.config` is sufficient for an ASP.NET Web API, but if that's not what you're working on, you'll need to add custom code to allow the `OPTIONS` header, within your web service. Basically, you need to create a message inspector and then some endpoint behavior that uses the message inspector class to add the required headers.

For code and an example service, see [the WCF page on enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html).

Comment: Not going to have the opportunity to test this right now before the bounty runs out, but this looks like it's in the right direction.

Comment: You might want to also check out [this blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/07/02/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-and-wcf/) from 2011, as it contains a service host factory that can save you the implementation time. It's a real headache compared to enabling CORS with other backends, but it's 100% possible.

Answer (score -1):

Have tried adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in header in `Response` as following(only if you want your WCF service be accessible from any domain),

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
```

In one of my Web API method, I used `UrlReferrer` for this.
The code looks like following

```
Uri referredURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://" + referredURL.Host);
```

But this method is little risky, as it is not guaranteed whether you will get the `UrlReferrer` or not because it depends on the client(browser).